# Golang https server passing certFile and kyeFile in terms of byte array

Tags: go, https

```
func ListenAndServeTLS(addr string, certFile string, keyFile string, handler Handler) error
```

Above is the function that I call to start an https server in Golang. It works without any problem. However, as I have more deployments, I don't want to put my key files everywhere. So I am thinking to let the program download the key file and cert file from a centralized place. If there would be a similar function receiving `[]byte` as opposed to `string`, it would be easy for me to do that. But it seems I don't see such function in the documentations.

Comment: Is it really that inconvenient to convert a byte slice into a string?

Comment: @Volker maybe I didn't make my question clear enough for you. What I wanted was to pass in the content of the key file in terms of byte array/slice instead of passing in the path of the key file in terms of string. I don't see how what you said is relevant to my question.

Comment: @Volker did you really understand the question before you made the comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking [at the source of `ListenAndServeTLS`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/883bc6ed0ea815293fe6309d66f967ea60630e87/src/net/http/server.go#L1853-L1880) it seems that there is no option, it always calls [`tls.LoadX509KeyPair`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#LoadX509KeyPair).
That's unfortunate; possibly worth submitting a feature request.

In the meantime, the `ListenAndServeTLS` method is not large, and (other than `tcpKeepAliveListener`) it does not use anything non-exported so it'd simple to copy the body of that method to your own function and replace `Load509KeyPair` with [`tls.X509KeyPair`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#X509KeyPair), which does take `[]byte` of PEM encoded data rather than filenames. (Or perhaps take a `tls.Certificate` argument instead.)

E.g. something like https://play.golang.org/p/ui_8dS8ouU

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/commit/f81f6d6ee8a7f578ab19ccb8b7dbc3b6fff81aa0
Since this commit, you can pass empty string to do that

Comment: Maxux: awesome, worked like a charm! So just define srv.TLSConfig = &tls.Config{Certificates: ... } before calling srv.ListenAndServeTLS("", "")